# Should historical SQL UTC Dates change when currently viewing in DST

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, dst

Let's say I have a date stored in **UTC** time in **SQL** using the **datetime** type. In C#, I am converting to the client using `.ToLocalTime().`

Will the time value itself be different depending on *when* I look at it? That is, during DST or not?

For example, the actual hour of this historic event (2022-09-30T16:00:00.00) is stored 4 hours ahead, so it converts as 12pm. This is correct. But when DST ends, and it's 5 hours ahead, will it show as being done at 11am? Is there a method to always show the actual hour it happened in the past, not adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because September 30 is always with DST. It doesn't matter if you check it in May or January, dates in September have always DST.

You can trivially confirm this yourself: Create a new DateTime object for 2022-02-03 (no DST) and print it today (October 4). Currently, we observe DST, but the date in February will still be output without DST, because DST is not applied in February.